# Multiplying a Matrix and a Vector

Tags: c, vector, matrix, multiplication

I need to multiply a matrix and a vector.

To accomplish that I have wrote a function with parameters :

`float** M` The maxtrix of dimensions : m x n.

`float* V` The vector of length n.

`float* R` Where I store the result, vector of length m, already allocated.

`int m, int n` The lengths.

Here is my code :

```
int i,j;

for (i=0;i<m;i++){
    for (j=0;j<n;j++){
            R[i]+=(M[i][j]*V[j]);
        }
}
```

The complete function code :

```
void m_mult_v(float** M, float* V, float* R, int m, int n) {

    int i,j;

    for (i=0;i<m;i++){
        for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
            R[i]+=(M[i][j]*V[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the result I got is not the right one. :-/ any idea ?

Thanks for your future answers !

**EDIT**

Solution found thanks for your tips !

I just added this portion of code, to set R to all zeros.

```
for (i=0;i<m;i++){
    R[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show your complete code.  Please also provide a sample input, the expected output, and the actual output.  Please also tell us what debugging you've done so far...

Comment: @MarekSebera i added from the beginning the right tag, i don't know why I my question got downgraded ...

Comment: I downvoted because you haven't provided your *complete* code, nor have you told us what input it fails on, nor how it fails, nor have you told us what you've learnt by debugging it.

Comment: @TheTime sorry, completely missed that. I haven't downvoted you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize R? If it's stack-allocated or allocated with malloc() its initial state is not defined.

Comment: @TheTime: But is it initialized to all zeros?

Comment: Allocated how? Did you zero-initialize it? Why don't you post a minimal example of compilable code that fails to produce the right answer?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth --' Your are right. R is initalized but not set to all zeros. Problem solved Thanks all !